# To get occupied vs to get busy

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, sentence-structure

Please imagine you have two naughty and noisy children who scream a lot. You are loosing your patience because of this and you are going to find a solution to the problem at hand. You buy a PlayStation device for them. After awhile your one of your neighbors asks you about the reason your children do not make those sounds as before! You say:

> **a)** They **have gotten occupied** since they’ve bought PlayStation.
>
> **b)** They **have gotten busy** since they’ve bought PlayStation.

Which one of the above mentioned self-made sentences sounds natural? If no one, then please let me know what how a native speaker would say it.

For me, the both verbs work properly and mean the same here.

Comment: neither sounds natural. Are we doing your homework? Wink...

Comment: <grump>I wish you'd gotten them books instead.</grump>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are busy playing their game.

They are occupied with their Playstation.

Their new Playstation is keeping them busy (or occupied).

Answer (score 2):

> They've gotten much quieter since they got a PlayStation

would be fine, since it defines the *change* of state; but I think most people would define the new state with *ADJ*+complement rather than a temporal.

> They've gotten fascinated with their PlayStation.
>   They've gotten absorbed in their PlayStation.
>   They've gotten wrapped up in their PlayStation.

. . . and so forth—there are dozens of possibilities.